# Kerberos Authorization in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load, authorization, performance-testing, kerberos

I have an application where it allows only to users who has granted access using Kerberos. I have added HTTP Authorization Manager in JMeter script. Below are the values.

- BaseURL: http://myapplication-url
- Username: DOMAIN\MYID or MYID
- Password: please-guess
- Domain: \
- Realm:
- Mechanism: Kerberos

When I execute it, I got the response stating that "You do not have rights to access the application."

There is no login page. When we invoke the URL, it will open the home page immediately. Manually it is working fine.

How do I solve above issue?

Also, if user 'B' (who doesn't have access to the application) executes the script, he got only the blank response with code 200 OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to perform the similar configuration in `krb5.conf`and `jaas.conf` files, the configuration should match your [DC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_controller)/[KDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378170(v=vs.85).aspx).

You will also need to add the next 2 lines to *system.properties* file

```
java.security.krb5.conf=krb5.conf
java.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf
```

All the files are located in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation.

Check out [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article for more information and some sample configuration.